# Adding a progressbar that reports the download (source included)

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

New to programming and here Im stuck where Im going to put the code to make a progress bar report the progress of download & writing of files.

The source will download a 100mb file in 6 parts and I wanted 2 progress bar, 1 label that will report the progress of:

1. download progress
2. Writing of file (if possible or is it redundant already?)
3. A label with the progress of downloaded_MB / MaxFileSize_Mb.
4. How can I make it even faster to download the file? Would adding partitions make it faster (which I doubt)?

Code is as follow.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1
    Dim efsize, fsize

    Public Class FileDownloader
        Public Start As Integer
        Public Count As Integer
        Public PathTemp As String
        Public Url As String

        Public Sub New(ByVal url As String, ByVal start As Integer, ByVal count As Integer)
            Me.Url = url
            Me.Start = start
            Me.Count = count
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Shared Function FormatFileSize(ByVal Size As Long) As String
        Try
            Dim KB As Integer = 1024
            Dim MB As Integer = KB * KB
            ' Return size of file in kilobytes.
            If Size < KB Then
                Return (Size.ToString("D") & " bytes")
            Else
                Select Case Size / KB
                    Case Is < 1000
                        Return (Size / KB).ToString("N") & " KB"
                    Case Is < 1000000
                        Return (Size / MB).ToString("N") & " MB"
                    Case Is < 10000000
                        Return (Size / MB / KB).ToString("N") & " GB"
                End Select
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Size.ToString
        End Try
    End Function
    Private Sub startDownload()
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000

        Dim url As String = "https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin"
        Dim filewonloadersList As List(Of FileDownloader) = New List(Of FileDownloader)()
        Dim req As Net.WebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(url)
        Dim response = req.GetResponse()
        req.Method = "HEAD"
        Dim resp As Net.WebResponse = req.GetResponse()
        Dim responseLength As Integer = Integer.Parse(resp.Headers.Get("Content-Length"))
        Dim parts As Integer = 6
        Dim eachSize = responseLength / parts
        Dim lastPartSize = eachSize + responseLength Mod parts

        For i As Integer = 0 To parts - 1 - 1
            filewonloadersList.Add(New FileDownloader(url, i * eachSize, eachSize))

        Next

        filewonloadersList.Add(New FileDownloader(url, (parts - 1) * eachSize, lastPartSize))
        Dim threads = New List(Of Thread)()

        For Each item In filewonloadersList
            Task.WhenAll(DoDownload(item))

        Next
    End Sub

    Public Async Function DoDownload(ByVal data As Object) As Task
retry:

        Try
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000

            Dim downloader = TryCast(data, FileDownloader)
            Dim req As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(downloader.Url), HttpWebRequest)
            req.AddRange(downloader.Start, downloader.Start + downloader.Count - 1) 'downloader.Start + downloader.Count - 1
            Dim response = Await req.GetResponseAsync()

            Using reponseStream = response.GetResponseStream()


                Using fs = New FileStream($"temp_{downloader.Start}.sth", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
                    Dim buffer = New Byte(1023) {}
                    Dim bytesRead As Integer = 0

                    Do
                        bytesRead = Await reponseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1024)

                        progMain.Value = fs.Length
                        Await fs.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                        Await fs.FlushAsync()

                    Loop While bytesRead > 0

                    fs.Close()

                    efsize = FormatFileSize(Convert.ToInt64(bytesRead))

                End Using
            End Using
        Catch e As Exception
            GoTo retry
        End Try
    End Function


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        startDownload()
    End Sub


End Class
```

I posted it here as a last resort as I am lost what to do next.

Please also point me to the right direction where to or what to do so I can learn more while I explore progamming.

I opted VB.net since I can easily follow it and is very newbie friendly.

Thank you!

Comment: Where are you calculating the progress? If you're not doing so then there's no progress to report. If you are doing so, that's where you report it. What is the actual problem here: calculating the progress or reporting it to the UI? You need to make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a ProgressBar in your form (let's say ProgressBar1), you can simply update its value each time there's a "progress" in your code.

For example, usually when you have a loop, you can report it:

```
ProgressBar1.MaxValue = 12
For i as Integer = 0 to 12
    '... some code
    ProgressBar1.Value = i
    Application.DoEvents()   'will update the UI
Next
```

and then the ProgressBar can show the amount percentage done.

In general, it is better to do it with right principles of MultiThread,
but as you mentioned, you are still a bit new and learning your way through.

Unrelated recommendation: it's better never to use GoTo (at all)